# Limited Wordpress Custom Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Hi to all I have a funtion to create a numeric pagination for blog posts:

```
function fb_paging_bar( $args = array() ) {

    $defaults = array(
        'range'           => 4,
        'custom_query'    => FALSE,
        'previous_string' => __( 'PREVIOUS', 'themename' ),
        'next_string'     => __( 'NEXT PAGE', 'themename' ),
        'view_fp'         => TRUE,
        'view_lp'         => TRUE,
        'before_output'   => '<div class="paginator" id="movie_paginator">',
        'after_output'    => '</div>'
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( 
        $args, 
        apply_filters( 'fb_paging_bar_defaults', $defaults )
    );

    $args['range'] = (int) $args['range'] - 1;
    if ( !$args['custom_query'] )
        $args['custom_query'] = @$GLOBALS['wp_query'];
    $count = (int) $args['custom_query']->max_num_pages;
    $page  = intval( get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
    $ceil  = ceil( $args['range'] / 2 );

    if ( $count <= 1 )
        return FALSE;

    if ( !$page )
        $page = 1;

    if ( $count > $args['range'] ) {
        if ( $page <= $args['range'] ) {
            $min = 1;
            $max = $args['range'] + 1;
        } elseif ( $page >= ($count - $ceil) ) {
            $min = $count - $args['range'];
            $max = $count;
        } elseif ( $page >= $args['range'] && $page < ($count - $ceil) ) {
            $min = $page - $ceil;
            $max = $page + $ceil;
        }
    } else {
        $min = 1;
        $max = $count;
    }

    $echo = '';
    $previous = intval($page) - 1;
    $previous = esc_attr( get_pagenum_link($previous) );
    if ( $previous && (1 != $page) )
        $echo .= '<a class="page page-prev" href="' . $previous . '" title="' . __( 'PREVIOUS', 'themename' ) . '">' . $args['previous_string'] . '</a>';
    $firstpage = esc_attr( get_pagenum_link(1) );

    if ( $args['view_fp'] && $firstpage && (1 != $page) )
        $echo .= '<a class="page" href="' . $firstpage . '">' . __( '1', 'themename' ) . '</a>';

    if ( !empty($min) && !empty($max) ) {
        for( $i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++ ) {
            if ($page == $i) {
                $echo .= '<span class="page page-mobile disabled">' . str_pad( (int)$i, 1, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) . '</span>';
            } else {
                $echo .= sprintf( '<a href="%s">%002d</a>', esc_attr( get_pagenum_link($i) ), $i );
            }
        }
    }

    if ($args['view_lp']) {
        $lastpage = esc_attr( get_pagenum_link($count) );
        if ( $lastpage && ($count != $page) ) {
            $count = str_pad( (int)$count, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
            $echo .= '<span class="page no-page page-mobile disabled">...</span><a class="page" href="' . $lastpage . '">' . $count . '</a>';
        }
    }

    $next = intval($page) + 1;
    $next = esc_attr( get_pagenum_link($next) );
    if ($next && ($count != $page) )
        $echo .= '<a class="page page-next" href="' . $next . '" title="' . __( 'NEXT PAGE', 'themename') . '">' . $args['next_string'] . '</a>';

    if ( isset($echo) )
        echo $args['before_output'] . $echo . $args['after_output'];
}
```

The result of this code above is like the first image

[image]

But Im trying to find the right way to add more numers because as u see this one shows only first,current and last number

is there any way to make it with more numbers like the second screenshot?

[image]

Comment: This is certainly the hard way to do this.  Have you checked out the wordpress built-in function [paginate_links()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)?

Comment: Also - this is a far more challenging problem to solve than you might think.  How many links should it show? How many before the ellipses? How many after the ellipses?

Comment: So as I told the function show like in the first image but the second image I did using photoshop just to give an idea because I got only errors I cannot change the function to show pagination like the second image

Comment: there are more simple functions to make a simple pagination but it doesnt let me add css classes, and previous next page texts, would be nice if you have any idea how to add some more numers after the current number